# Time complexity in terms of big O for a reverse vector

Tags: c++, vector, time, complexity-theory

```
template <typename T>
void reverseVector(vector<T> &vec, int start, int end) {
   if(start < end) {
       char temp = vec[start];
       vec[start] = vec[end];
       vec[end] = temp; 
       reverseVector(vec, start + 1, end – 1); }
   }
}
```

Assuming N = vec.size() what would be the time complexity of this method?

Assuming I am correct, a getting and setting a vector has time O(1). Thus, the first 3 lines in the if statement are all O(1) each. Then, the method recursively calls itself and each time the function becomes smaller, iterating n(n-1)(n-2)... times. So my answer would be O(n!) for this method. Am I correct?

edit: similar syntax, but with linked list

```
template <typename T>
void reverseLinkedList(list<T> &lst, int start, int end) {
  if(start < end) {
    char temp = lst[start];
    lst[start] = lst[end];
    lst[end] = temp;
    reverseLinkedList(lst, start + 1, end – 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is `O(n)`.

You swap elements `n/2` times: (0 with n-1), (1 with  n-2), ... (n/2 - 1 with  n/2 + 1)

Comment: So does the recursive call not affect the time complexity in this case?

Comment: Not at all. You function is equivalent to ``while(start < end) {... start + 1; end - 1;}``

Comment: Okay.. my understanding of big-oh notation is not all that strong, but I somewhat understand. If this were instead a method with similar syntax that reversed a linked list, how would the time complexity change?

Comment: If accessing the element at index ``i`` takes ``O(n)`` time, then you would still swap ``O(n)`` times, but each swapping would take ``O(n)``. So the overall time complexity would be ``O(n^2)`` using the same algorithm.

Comment: I added the code I had for reversing a linked list. So it becomes O(n^2) because accessing a linked list has different time complexity to a vector?

Comment: Yes if you do it this way. Otherwise, you can just use iterator, one start from the begining and the other one starting from the end. The later solution would be ``O(n)``